# Multiplying 2 ranges together

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting syntax error in the line

`Range("E4:E" & ColALastRow) =Application.WorksheetFunction.Product=(Range("A4:A" & ColALastRow), Range("D4:D" & LastRowOfD))`

Col A and Col D have values. I want to multiply them together to col E. Below is my code so far.

```
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim ColALastRow As Long, LastRowOfD As Long
    
    ColALastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A" & ColALastRow)
    LastRowOfD = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("E4:E" & ColALastRow) =Application.WorksheetFunction.Product=(Range("A4:A" & ColALastRow), Range("D4:D" & LastRowOfD))
```

Comment: won't the last filled cell be the same for both columns?

Comment: I dont get what you mean

Comment: All ranges involved must have same size, that means same quantity of cells. Make sure that happens

Comment: ya, all the ranges have same number of rows

Comment: `PRODUCT()` does not work that way. It will come up with a sum of the multiplication of all values provides. So just a ***single*** value which you are now trying to copy over to multiple cells in the E-column. That being said you also have syntax error since you don't want that second "=".

Comment: Unless A has one more than D or D has one more than A...

Comment: so how do i multiply the 2 ranges then?

Comment: What about that `=` after `Application.WorksheetFunction.Product`?.

Comment: it didnt work, the answer for me below also suddenly did not work. It divides instead of multiplying

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your approach like below and get desired results.

```
Sub ProductofTwoCol()
    With Range("E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=A1*D1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what does .value = .value mean?

Comment: @Chewjunnie It gets rid of the formula and leaves cell with calculated value.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: wait, why it suddenly dosent work? It actually divides

Comment: @Chewjunnie it works for me as it should. If it is locale specific issue then I am not sure about it. However, you can step through the code using `F8` key and check intermediate step outcomes.